# PHP Login based on "role" of user

Tags: php, class, authentication

My code uses a Login Class to authenticate. I need to have a variable based on the user's login information (role) that will direct admin users to a separate page.
Here I tried to set a `$role` variable inside my login class:

```
private function getUserRole($role)
{
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT role FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');
        $query_user->bindValue(':role', $role, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_user->execute();
        return $query_user->fetchObject();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here on my `index.php` page I am trying to direct the login traffic:

```
require_once('classes/Login.php');
$login = new Login();
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true and $login->getUserRole() == 'admin'){
    include("views/logged_in.html");
} else {
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

I am new to using a login class and I am working with my existing code so any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you're using the `:user_name` named placeholder in what you posted; you only used `:role`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `user_name` instead of `role`

```
private function getUserRole($user_name)
{
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT role FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');
        $query_user->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_user->execute();

        return $query_user->fetchObject();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once('classes/Login.php');

$login = new Login();

if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true and $login->getUserRole($user_name) == 'admin') {
    include("views/logged_in.html");
} else {
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Comment: I have a column of "user_name" but I also have a column of "role" in my database. My intention is to reference the role column for the user logging in and check it with an if statement to see if their role is "admin".  Functions in login.php handle the login but i'm not sure how exactly the instance of the class "login" can be checked against the user's role. You can see that one function "isUserLoggedIn()" checks if they are logged in but how can I write a function that can be checked on my index.php page with that same if statement?

Comment: I may need to add more code from login.php so you can see what I'm working with. Creating the function in login.php and referencing it in index.php as you stated isn't working. It won't let me get past the login screen meaning it isn't passing my if statement to let me through if role was referenced for "admin".